# Unreal Engine 4 не видит Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

Можно ли его как то указать в настройках движка (как в Unity)?

Comment: Вам необходимо использовать VS 2019 по умолчанию?

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего UE 4 не видит по той причине, что в самом Visual Studio отсутствуют необходимые пакеты для разработки игр. Вам следует запустить Visual Studio Installer, выбрать версию Visual Studio которая у вас установлена и нажать "Изменить" и выбрать пункт для разработки игр и убедиться, что галочка стоит здесь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Более подробное руководство:** https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Development/VisualStudioSetup/index.html